# Permanently store headers files in dev c++

Tags: c++

Could i save headers files permanently in dev c++ so that i don't have to include every time i write new code.
for example

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
```

and so on. If yes then how can i do that.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Also, those are not standard C++ header files, and DevC++ is not a good C++ IDE. Wherever you are learning this stuff from, I would strongly advise learning it from somewhere else.

Comment: How often do you get to include iostream in a real world application, anyway... It doesn't hurt to type it every time you need it.

Comment: Try to use pre-compiled headers, keyword: stdafx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that with any IDE that some headers are included by default.

The closest thing you can do is to provide a single header file

```
 #include "MyProject.h"
```

that just includes all the other header files:

`MyProject.h`:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
```

---

You should note that `conio.h` and `iostream.h` aren't standard c++ headers, and that code isn't portable because of that.